# How to configure entities in zf2 for ManyToOne unidirectional doctrine mapping

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, many-to-one

I'm having trouble developing a form in zf2 using a doctrine ManyToOne unidirectional relationship.  My entities look like this:

```
namespace AdminMyPages\Entity;

class MyPageItem
{
    // ... 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyMessage")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="myMessageID", referencedColumnName="myMessageID")
     **/
    private $myMessage;

    // ... 

    /**
     * Allow null to remove association
     *
     * @param Collection $myMessage
     */
    public function setMyMessage(Collection $myMessage = null)
    {
        $this->myMessage = $myMessage;
    }

    /**
     * @return myMessage
     */
    public function getMyMessage()
    {
        return $this->myMessage;
    }

}

class MyMessage
{
    // ... 
}
```

The fieldset for `MyPageItemFieldset` looks like this:

```
namespace AdminMyPages\Form;

class MyPageItemFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('mypage-item-fieldset');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'AdminMyPages\Entity\MyPageItem'))
             ->setObject(new MyPageItem());

        // ...

        $myMessageFieldset = new MyMessageFieldset($objectManager);
        $this->add(array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name'    => 'myMessage',
            'options' => array(
                'count'           => 1,
                'target_element' => $myMessageFieldset
            )
        ));

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {

        // ...

        return array(
            'myMessage' => array(
                'required' => false
            ),
        );

    }

}
```

With this configuration I am able to "get" data from the `MyMessage` through `getMyMessage()`, so I know that the tables have been joined.  However, when I try to bind the entity in a form, I get an error:

File:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\GetOut\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Form\Element\Collection.php:167
```

Message:

```
Zend\Form\Element\Collection::setObject expects an array or Traversable object argument; received "DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG__\AdminMyPages\Entity\MyMessage"
```

Stack trace:

```
#0  ...  Zend\Form\Element\Collection->setObject(Object(DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG__\AdminMyPages\Entity\MyMessage))
    ...
```

One thought I have is that, since the ManyToOne relationship will only produce a single match, the `MyMessage` fieldset is hardly a collection - it's just one item - so `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` might not be the right form element to use.  But, if it's not a collection, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally right. Your MyMessage should not be a `Collection`. It should simply be an instance of `MyMessage`.

You defined a `ManyToOne` between `MyPageItem` and `MyMessage` meaning one page item has one message and  a message has many page items. But since it is a unidirectional relationship that last part is never defined.

So the setter should look like this:

```
/**
 * @param MyMessage $myMessage
 */
public function setMyMessage(MyMessage $myMessage = null)
{
    $this->myMessage = $myMessage;
}
```

And you should also change your form field definition to a single `MyMessage` item.